# WCF. Set user credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

Sorry, my english is bad.

I have wcf services project and asp.net mvc project
I'm using ninject wcf client extension to inject services like in this example

```
 Bind<IService>().ToServiceChannel();
```

Now i'm I need to add authentication and authorization for wcf services. I have implemented `UserNamePasswordValidator` and `IAuthorizationPolicy`.

In all examples used service reference and user credentials added like here:

```
ServiceClient host = new ServiceClient();
host.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
host.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
```

But i didn't create service reference. I have only interfaces. And use it like here:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    public HomeController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;    
    }
}
```

How I can add user credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a channelFactory for you to set the user credentials:

Example :

```
var result = new ChannelFactory<IService>("*", new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
    result.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
    result.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```